# How can I copy the text by click the div?

Tags: vue.js

How can I copy the text by click the `div` in the render function?

in the bellow you can see the `div`, I want to click it, then the clipboard can copy the text of it.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

my code of render function is bellow:

```
      h(
         'div',
         {slot:"content"},
         [
           h(
            'ul',
             params.row.ipv4s.map((item, index) => {
               return h('li', [h('span', {}, index + 1 + '. ' + item.ip)])

             })
           )
         ]
       )
```

how can I realize my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help you out:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard

Tackling this yourself can be a pretty cumbersome task for something which should have been implemented with an API across all browsers but unfortunately isn't.